# count the user's input

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to count the user input and have it alert it to me as a integer.

My jQuery is this:

```
jQuery("#box4").keyup(function () {
    var length = parseInt(jQuery("#box4").val() + 1);
    alert(length);
});
```

I keep getting NaN which means the string can't be converted to an integer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use `.length` property, `parseInt` doesn't return length of the strings.

Comment: Read [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 1):

Count length of user input

```
var length = jQuery("#box4").val().length+ 1;
alert(length);
```

or better

```
var length = this.value.length+ 1;
alert(length);
```

---

References

[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

[length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#box4").keyup(function () {
    alert(this.value.length);
});
```